# How to change the default version of gcc man page?

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu-14.04, manpage

I have installed `gcc-4.8` and `gcc-6`. The default gcc version is `gcc-4.8`, but I want to change the default gcc version to `gcc-6`, so I do the following:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 10
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 20
```

then the default gcc version has changed to `gcc-6`, but when I run command

```
$ man gcc
```

the man page version of gcc is still `gcc-4.8`. How can I change the man page version of gcc to `gcc-6`? Thanks!
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Try `apt-get remove gcc-doc` and then look for an updated version of that package to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

1. Find the location of `gcc-6` man page:

   ```
   $ locate gcc-6 | grep 'man'             
   /usr/share/man/man1/gcc-6.1.gz            
   /usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6.1.gz
   ```

   so the location of `gcc-6` man page is `/usr/share/man/man1/gcc-6.1.gz`
2. Remove the file `/usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz` if it exist:

   ```
   $ sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
   ```
3. Create a symbolic link to `/usr/share/man/man1/gcc-6.1.gz`:

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/share/man/man1/gcc-6.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
   ```

Then run comman:

```
$ man gcc
```

You will see the man page version of gcc has changed to `gcc-6`.
Sorry for my English.